# How to clean cairo surface area without using a png image

Tags: gtk, cairo

This will clean the whole surface:

```c
void surface_clean(Mpaint *mpaint)
{
    mpaint->surface=cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("cxl.cache.png");
}
```

I only want to clean the area in a `cairo_surface_t` by `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`.

Is there any interface for this?

Comment: You are not supposed to manipulate surfaces like that. Instead, you are supposed to create a cairo context (`cairo_t`) that is backed by the given surface and then draw onto the context; the context will then alter the surface. Your current code does not actually clear the surface; instead, it replaces the old surface with a new one without freeing the old one first (so not only is your code wrong, but you also have a memory leak).

Comment: overlay = gtk_overlay_new (); gtk_overlay_add_overlay (GTK_OVERLAY (overlay), image);
  gtk_overlay_add_overlay (GTK_OVERLAY (overlay), mpaint.mwidget.darea); to add a bg image, then creat a image surface . it works

Answer (score 7):

Check `CAIRO_OPERATOR_*` [here](https://cairographics.org/operators/). Here is some PyCairo showing how to use it:

```py
ctx.set_source_rgba(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
ctx.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_CLEAR)
ctx.rectangle(x, y, width, height)
ctx.paint_with_alpha(1.0)
```

Comment: don't forget to come back to a default operator like ctx.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_OVER) for example : )